# How do I use select alias inside GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sql-server-group-concat

1. I am averaging 4 columns and giving an alias `score`.
2. Now, I am trying to use `score` alias inside GROUP_CONCAT to get `rank`.
3. Everything works except when I add `(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC) FROM math )) AS rank`.
4. I understand it does not work because `score` does not exist in the `math` table. But what do I need to do to make it work?

Here is my query in laravel 5.5 -

`$ranking = DB::select('SELECT id, (a.addition_accuracy + a.subtraction_accuracy + a.multiplication_accuracy + a.division_accuracy)/4 as score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score ORDER BY score DESC) FROM math )) AS rank FROM math a where level = 5');`

1. I get 500 server error from above query.
2. I am expecting below output

````
    {
        "id": 38,
        "score": 99.24250030517578,
        "rank": 1

    },
    {
        "id": 51,
        "score": 84.88500213623047,
        "rank": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 204,
        "score": 69.27500057220459,
        "rank": 3
    }
]```
````

Comment: Post sample data and expected results.

Comment: @forpas I have added what I expect to see

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas AWS Aurora MySQl 5.6 global_10a

Comment: But you haven't added what we expect to see. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for your query.
I changed it to checl also the score

```
SELECT 
  id
  , (a.addition_accuracy + a.subtraction_accuracy + a.multiplication_accuracy + a.division_accuracy)/4 as score
  ,if(@score = score,@rank:= @rank,@rank:= @rank+1) as rank
  ,  @score := score
  FROM math a,(SELECT @rank :=0) b ,(SELECT @score :=0) c
  where level = 5
  ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 3
```

As i said some data as test ground would be nice

Comment: I have just added what I expect to see

Comment: Edited answer gives ranking perfectly but little problem. When two person have same score it gives one person a rank 1 and second person a rank 2. How do I make it so that it gives both rank 1.   {
        "id": 38,
        "score": 99.24250030517578,
        "rank": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 356,
        "score": 99.24250030517578,
        "rank": 2
    }

Comment: I had to change the "ORDER BY score" to "ORDER BY score desc"

Comment: Try this new changed version, it checks if the score is the same it doesn't change the rank..

Comment: It gives error. I think it's not able to put `score` in `@score`. It breaks right when I add `@score := score`

Comment: Worked. Instd of putting `score` alias I put the whole thing- ```SELECT 
  id
  , (a.addition_accuracy + a.subtraction_accuracy + a.multiplication_accuracy + a.division_accuracy)/4 as score
  ,if(@newScore = (a.addition_accuracy + a.subtraction_accuracy + a.multiplication_accuracy + a.division_accuracy)/4,@rank:= @rank,@rank:= @rank+1) as rank
  ,  @newScore := (a.addition_accuracy + a.subtraction_accuracy + a.multiplication_accuracy + a.division_accuracy)/4 as newScore
  FROM math a,(SELECT @rank :=0) b ,(SELECT @newScore :=0) c
  where level = 5
  ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 3```